# Black body: radiation in all frequencies

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

How can a black body emit light in all frequencies? Doesn't the light come from electrons changing their discrete energy state from one orbital to another? Even if you had many possible discrete energy changes, the light spectrum would still not be continuous.
Similar, how can a black body absorb light with all frequencies? I’m aware, that a perfect black body doesn’t exist, but how does it work in those objects coming close to a perfect black body?

Comment: You are asking how to create a perfect black body in practice yet acknowledging that you know that such things cannot be done. The comparison is, we imagine an ideal gas yet a perfect ideal gas does not exist. Does this conflict give you comparable problems?

Answer (score 1):

Black bodies do not radiate at all frequencies, they radiate in a spread spectrum of different frequencies with upper and lower asymptotic bounds.

That radiation is not created by electrons switching orbitals around the atom. it comes from the electrons getting accelerated and decelerated as those atoms vibrate around randomly because of their thermal energy. Since those accelerations can have almost any magnitude and direction, the resulting radiation can have a broad range of possible frequencies.